# How to add another device to Clash of Clans without losing anything?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the beginning I played Clash of Clans on my IPhone (I have one account.) After a year my brother played the game on his IPad and IPhone(he has one account, too.) Now we (me and my brother) play clash of clans on 3 devices(two accounts.) I want to play the game on MY Ipad without creating a new apple id. How do you do that without losing my brother's account???

Comment: why would you using it on your iPad affect your brothers account on his?

Comment: and why can't you just do whatever your brother did to have 2 devices on 1 account?

Comment: Becose we have the same apple id and my brother's account could be losed

Comment: If you've got the same Apple ID, but you use the app on each of your iPhones without issue, then surely the Apple ID is not strongly tied to the clash of clans account?

Comment: If you both have the same Apple ID, you both have the same Clash Of Clans account.

Comment: This is so vague. Are you getting a new iPad or are you taking over your brother's iPad? If the former (which is the impression you've given us in your question), you obviously will set it up with your account. What does that have to do your brother's account? It makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will be interfered with during the process. If your brother's Apple ID is not the same as the one you are using, it will be fine. All you have to do is sign in to your Apple ID and your Game Center and you should be fine.

Comment: If signing in to a new account would load a different village, you will see a "Load Village XXXX" question warning you that "Progress will be lost" you must also type "CONFIRM" to load the alternate village.  In other words, sign in may not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are getting at fundamentally is whether you can transfer the progress of a Village from one iOS device to another, but you partially already know the answer because your brother is doing it with his iPhone and iPad.  The dilemma is that you both have the same Apple ID, which could present a problem if your Village was tied to your Apple ID.  Clash of Clans, like most iOS games actually ties your progress to your GameCenter account (which can be the same as your Apple ID, or can be different).  SuperCell gives details of transferring Villages between devices in a FAQ article [**here**](https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421682-Can-I-transfer-my-village-to-a-new-device-).

Based on what you've described, I don't think it is likely that both you and your brother have the same **Gamecenter account**.  You can verify this by opening Settings->Gamecenter on your device and his device and check to see that the accounts that are logged in are not the same.  If they were, you'd most likely be playing the same Village across your past 3 devices.  Either way, if you want to share a device without conflicts, you'll need unique Gamecenter accounts.  On a given device, when you log out of one account and log into the other you should load the other account's Village.

As an aside, Apple doesn't exactly make it easy to switch back and forth constantly between GameCenter accounts.  If what you are seeking is just a one time switch to be sure you aren't overwriting each others villages, linking to separate GC accounts will solve your problem.  If you are trying to use one device with two villages, you may find that the constant GC account switching is more trouble than it is worth (given that you already have 2-3 other devices in play in this scenario).

Comment: Good answer.  Just to clarify a _GameCenter_ account is an _**AppleID**_ - but it may not be the same _AppleID_ as that which is used e.g. for purchases and iCloud, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you using the same Apple id?  If you are it still doesn't matter, just go into your iPad go into settings in Clash of Clans, click link device and then click `this is my new device`. And on your iPhone go to setting in Clash of Clans and click link device but this time click this is my old deviCe. Wait a few seconds and it should be done!